# Lie brackets of correlated vector fields

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined as it follows: $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} e^x-e^y \\ e^x+e^y \\ e^z-e^y\end{pmatrix}.$$
I have to find the two fields $f$-correlated to $\frac \partial {\partial y}$ and $\frac {\partial} {\partial z}$; the question is to make esplicite the fields defined like this: $$V_1:\begin{pmatrix} e^x-e^y \\ e^x+e^y \\ e^z-e^y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} e^x\\ e^y \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ V_2:\begin{pmatrix} e^x-e^y \\ e^x+e^y \\ e^z-e^y\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ -e^y \\ e^z\end{pmatrix}.$$ I found that $$V_1:\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} \frac {x+y} 2\\ \frac {y-x} 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ V_2:\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ \frac {x-y} 2 \\ z+\frac {y-x} 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
This seems correct to me, but when I calculate $[V_1,V_2]$ I don't obtain $0$ as I should (because the commutator of $\frac \partial {\partial y}$ and $\frac {\partial} {\partial z}$ is $0$). For example,  consider the first component of  $[V_1,V_2]$: the result is $-\frac{x-y} 4$, not $0$. Where am I wrong? I made the calculations three times, maybe there is some concept that I misunderstood. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What is $f$-correlated ?

Comment: @SiKucing given a smooth map $f:M \to N$, a pair of vector fields on $M$ and $N$ are $f$-related if the vector field on $N$ is the pushforward of the vector field on $M$. OP is using the fact that the Lie bracket is natural so $[f_\ast V, f_\ast W] = f_\ast[V,W]$

Comment: In English, this is $f$-*related*. But I do not understand what you're doing. Did you calculate the derivative of $f$?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what you're doing. Write $f(x,y,z) = (u,v,w)$ and note that
$$f_*\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = e^y\begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \frac12(u-v) \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\Big)$$
and
$$f_*\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = e^z\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \big(w+\frac12(v-u)\big)\frac{\partial}{\partial w}.$$
Now compute the Lie bracket.